# c# Cache Control in code or IIS 6

Tags: c#, iis, http-headers, 3g, http-caching

When one of my websites is viewed over a mobile 3G network the network operator o2 in this case is rewriting the page and embedding all the styles in-line, this is causing the page to break. As the styles rules are not followed properly.

Now I understand from the guys at o2 that I can stop this happening by adding a Cache Control heading of "no-transform" to my site.

The problem is that adding this via IIS dosn't seam to do anything. and you cant add the cache control "no-transform" via code in .net as its not one of the system.Web.HttpCacheability options.

Any idea how I can get this header in and stop the page being tampered with by the mobile operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Response.AddHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524327%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method, like this:

```
Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-transform");
```

Verified this with Firebug, and it looks OK.

Comment: Great works perfectly, still not sure why adding it to the IIS header was just ignored, but never mind.

Answer (score 4):

Response.Cache.SetNoTransforms in Page_Load

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could add a meta element to your HTML, like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-transform" />
```

Comment: Should work, but with some network operators like o2 for example they just ignores it we rewrite your HTML, unless its in the header request.